# Variable as argument name

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use the value of a variable as the name of an argument, something like this (but not exactly this, as it doesn't work):

```
$processData = Split-Path $processData -($variable.split)
```

`$variable` is actually some XML, and the `split` property can either be 'parent' or 'leaf'. I can use this approach, and it works fine:

```
switch ($variable.split) {
    parent {
        $processData = Split-Path $processData -Parent
    }
    leaf {
        $processData = Split-Path $processData -Leaf
    }
}
```

But using the variable directly would be more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

[Splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) should do what you want:

```
$params = @{
    Path = $processData
    $variable.split = $true
}
$processData = Split-Path @params
```

Not really much less code than a `switch` statement, though:

```
$processData = switch ($variable.split) {
    parent { Split-Path $processData -Parent }
    leaf   { Split-Path $processData -Leaf }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could use `invoke-Expression` also but that could have negative implications.

Comment: Correct. Using `Invoke-Expression` is prone to making you vulnerable to command injection.